# can the female plate be used in conjunction with other equipment and then sold legally? does that break this patent?

Tags: patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [US4218107](https://www.google.com/patents/US4218107)

Answer (score 1):

This patent has expired (probably in 1997). This means you can not infringe on this patent. This doesn't mean there are not other relevant patents that may or may not be still active.

Answer (score 0):

Patent expired long ago so no problem will be faced.